# How to filter a column containing UUID Objects in Polars

Tags: python, uuid, python-polars

I have a Polars DataFrame containing UUID types in column `id`. I strongly prefer to keep these stored as UUIDs, without converting them to str/int etc. before creating the DataFrame. Creating `df` from my data works fine, but I encounter an error if I try to filter on column `id`.

How can I filter column `id` by a given UUID?

```py
import polars as pl
from uuid import UUID

df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        {"message": "foo", "id": UUID("925afb28-f437-4c46-b9b2-ae9ebb7899a9")},
        {"message": "bar", "id": UUID("f9278c55-4c11-4b68-a1aa-de9d6086efb6")},
    ],
    schema={"message": pl.String, "id": pl.Object},
)

df.shape
>> (2, 2)

df.filter(pl.col("id").eq(UUID("925afb28-f437-4c46-b9b2-ae9ebb7899a9")))
>> TypeError: invalid literal value: '925afb28-f437-4c46-b9b2-ae9ebb7899a9'

df.filter(pl.col("id").eq(str(UUID("925afb28-f437-4c46-b9b2-ae9ebb7899a9"))))
>> ComputeError: cannot cast 'Object' type
```

Comment: Why do you strongly prefer to keep these stored as UUID python objects instead of strings? polars has limited support for Objects which basically means you can store them but once you store them polars doesn't know what they are and can't do anything with them.

Comment: These will frequently be used for lookups and if, if not used as UUIDs directly, I will need to constantly go in/out of strings (whether by .hex or str(). This would be a one-off since other columns/types wouldn't require any munging.

Comment: polars is optimized around arrow memory which has fixed dtypes. If you're using python objects then you not only don't get those optimizations, but you don't get anything because all of its operations are built with the expectation that they're operating on arrow memory. It's really that stark.

Comment: UUIDs should be backed by ints, in which case the conversion should be pretty efficient: `UUID(int=my_int)` should really take no time at all.

Answer (score 2):

As @Dean MacGregor already pointed out, you should *strongly* avoid relying on any data of type `object` and instead use one of the underlying [arrow types](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/datatypes.html).

Still, in your example it would be possible to filter based on a comparison with another object of class `UUID` as follows.

```py
(
    df
    .filter(
        pl.col("id").map_elements(lambda id: id == UUID("925afb28-f437-4c46-b9b2-ae9ebb7899a9"))
    )
)
```

**Output.**

```py
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ message ┆ id                                │
│ ---     ┆ ---                               │
│ str     ┆ object                            │
╞═════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ foo     ┆ 925afb28-f437-4c46-b9b2-ae9ebb78… │
└─────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Again, here polars even warns of using [`pl.Series.map_elements`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.map_elements.html) in the documentation as the native expressions API should be preferred.

Comment: **Note.** I also thought about explicitly creating a literal column using [`pl.lit(...)`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.lit.html) and setting `allow_object = True`. However, in polars 0.20.5 I get a `PanicException` "not implemented".